# Boxing and Unboxing in C#

Tags: c#, heap-memory, boxing

In C#, according to the docmentation,
"Boxing a value type packages it inside an instance of the Object reference type. This allows the value type to be stored on the garbage collected heap."

What happens if  <strike>there is no "garbage collected heap"?</strike>the garbage collected heap is completely allocated and there is no "garbage collected heap" memory available?
Will it throw an exception or allocated somewhere else?

Comment: What implementation of C# are you using that has no GC heap?

Comment: How can a garbage collected heap be missing from a system that inherently relies on a garbage collector?

Comment: Actually, what implementation of the *.Net Framework*

Comment: @AndreCalil, yes and no. You could write an implementation of C# that does boxing, and stores the values somewhere other than a GC heap.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I see. But the *GC* itself is an implementation of the framework, right?

Comment: @AndreCalil, namely the CLR, but yes. IMO, the two are so tightly coupled, that it's instances like this where it's hard to draw the line.  After all, in C++/CLI, the objects are created with the `gcnew` operator.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart So, how would someone be able to store an object outside the heap?

Comment: @AndreCalil I'm getting outside of my range of knowledge here, and really just hypothesizing. I'm just saying it's either specified or implied by the C# language spec that there exists a GC heap, but its up to the CLR to implement it.

Comment: I am asking in a general sense (for any C# version.) what I meant by "no garbage collected heap" is that if all the garbage collected heap is allocated, will it throw an exception or allocate the variable in some other place

Comment: @Hari the heap has a dynamic size, it's not like a process stack. The CLR will request more memory to the OS if it's needed.

Comment: Thanks Andre, So it is not always the "garbage collected heap", isn't it?

Comment: @Hari It's more like *garbage collector's heap*. That is, objects stored at this memory space are "inspected" by the GC. However, it's most known as only *heap*, because there's no other heap in the current CLR implementation =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an object allocation like any other. If there's no memory available and none can be made available through garbage collection, you'll get an [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx).

You can think of this code:

```
int x = 10;
object o = x;
```

as being like:

```
int x = 10;
object o = new Int32_Wrapper(x);
```

where `Int32_Wrapper` would be the "boxed int" class. (You can't do this explicitly in C#, but that's the basic effect.)

Answer (score 0):

It's more like garbage collector's heap. That is, objects stored at this memory space are "inspected" by the GC. However, it's most known as only heap, because there's no other heap in the current CLR implementation =)

– Andre Calil

Comment: Thanks for the credit, but I'm not the expert here. If someone could get **Jon Skeet** to this question, he would be of much help =)

Comment: then why not post "If someone could get @JonSkeet to this question, he would be of much help" =)

Comment: @Hari I'm sorry I accidentally downvoted your answer (easy to do on an iPad) and didn't notice until after the undo period.  If I understand [this correctly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50035/accidental-voting) you'd have to edit your answer for me to undo the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

When the garbage collected heap is completely allocated, GC will be triggered to free memory, more memory (from OS managed VM) could be added to managed heap, until no more is available, at which point out of memory exception will be thrown.